# Rolling count SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a data base where I am query it to retrieve count. The question I have now is this: I am doing a select statement like below

```
Select count(distinct(ID)) as countID
      ,Activity
from Activity_Data
group by Activity_rank
order by countID desc
```

This give me back this

```
Activity   Distinct Count
AAA        100
BBB        90
CCC        80
```

What I am trying to achieve is a rolling count where

```
Activity   Distinct Count   Rolling Count
AAA        100              100
BBB        90               190
CCC        80               270
```

I tried doing this

```
    Select count(distinct(ID)) as countID
         , sum(count(distinct(ID))) as SumID
         , Activity from Activity_Data
    group by Activity_rank
    order by countID desc
```

but it gave me a **not a GROUP BY expression**

Not too sure what I am doing wrong and would appreciate guidance.

regards

Answer (score 1):

You are close.  You need an analytic function:

```
Select count(distinct ID) as countID,
       sum(count(distinct ID)) over (order by count(distinct ID) desc)
from Activity_Data
group by Activity_rank 
order by countID desc;
```

Comment: I did this but it gave me a ORA-06550: line 1, column 118: ORA-00904: "COUNTID": invalid identifier

Comment: @AdrianLeeXinhan . . . I fixed that.  I just hadn't noticed that `countId` is the result of the aggregation, not a column in the table.

Comment: Ah I was able to do it now!!! :D I took the over function and it worked. thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can nest aggregate functions. Try this is instead:

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT
Activity,
COUNT(DISTINCT ID) as CountID
FROM Activity_Data
GROUP BY Activity)

Select Activity, CountID, sum(CountID) OVER (ORDER BY ACTIVITY) as RollingSubtotal
FROM CTE
ORDER BY ACTIVITY
```